# Implementing the Clonable interface, but don't have to override the clone() method

Tags: java, interface

I'm learning Java and there is something that I couldn't understand.
If I understand correctly, by implementing an interface I am forced to implement all the methods that the interface has.

But, what in the case of the **Clonable**? If I implement it, I'm not forced to implement the **clone** method. Why is this happening?

Comment: I don't think there's anyone who really understands why it was designed like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Clonable` is a marker interface, which let you know that object can be cloned. You are not forced to implement `clone` method, because this method already exists in your class with `protected` access modifier (inherit from Object::clone).

Comment: By saying "marker interface" you mean that the Clonable interface is empty?

Comment: yes, if you will look inside of this interface, there is no methods.

Answer (score 0):

Because Cloneable interface does not have such method.